# Where is rootScope values are stored? In cookie or local storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, local-storage, rootscope

### Where is `rootScope` values are stored? In cookie or local storage?

I have a small doubt about `rootScope` in `angularjs`.

> I have passing a value between two controllers, So I have using the `$rootScope`.

- I want to know how to `rootScope` Working? and where is the `rootScope` data stored?
- In `Local Storage` or `cookie` or anything else?

Comment: You can say $rootScope is like a global variable within scope of angular stored in scope of page.

Comment: It's just stored in memory, basically like a global variable.  It will not survive a full page reload (F5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When switching controllers (or routes or states) in AngularJS only what's inside the controller closure is destroyed, anything outside of it is not. `$rootScope` is a service instantiated only once on the page so when you switch controllers it is not destroyed. That's why it's persistent. If you *reload* the whole page (hit [F5] in your browser) then everything in it is lost.

This is something fundamental for the whole Single Page Application pattern.

If you look into [the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L59) for this service you won't find anything related to cross-page persistence.

Comment: **If you reload the whole page (hit [F5] in your browser) then everything in it is lost.**  : Are you sure, the rootScope values will clear after i pres F5?

Comment: Yes. I am 100% sure about this. Check out the sources.

Comment: I did't checkout this, i hope you man : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374643/rootscope-value-used-in-a-controller-is-overridden-when-refreshing-the-page-use

Comment: You should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940974/maintain-model-of-scope-when-changing-between-views-in-angularjs

Comment: okay thanks you  sir, I will accept your  answer. thanks again. +1